# How to get the number which is after point from a float number in typescript

Tags: typescript

how to get the number, which is after the point in a float number in typescript. 
e.g.

2.3 I want to get 3 as return

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split() method by converting the decimal value to String.

Answer (score 0):

I will try with something simple like:

```
const num = 2.3;
const decimals = (num - Math.floor(num));​ // 0.3
```

so you get the integer part and then you subtract it from the original number
 in this way there's no need to do any string/number/string conversion

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Gurdevs answer

```js
const num = 2.3
console.log(num.toString().split('.')[1])
```